# Singular homology $S^{n}$ with rational coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology

What does $H_{i} (S^{n} , \mathbb{Q} )$ equal? Where this denotes singular homology with rational coefficients.

Comment: I'm trying to use the Lefschetz fixed point theorem for $S^{3}$. This isn't homework.

Comment: That's fine, but you should include those details in your post, together with any other information about the problem that you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [universal coefficient theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem) for homology, we have the following short exact sequence:
$$
0 \to H_i(X; \Bbb Z) \otimes \Bbb Q \to H_i(X; \Bbb Q) \to \operatorname{Tor}(H_{i-1}(X; \Bbb Z), \Bbb Q) \to 0.
$$

Since $\Bbb Q$ is torsionfree, we have the isomorphism:
$$
H_i(X; \Bbb Q) \cong H_i(X; \Bbb Z) \otimes \Bbb Q.
$$

This works with any space $X$.

Alternatively for $S^n$, you can follow the same inductive proof that computes homology with $\Bbb Z$ with coefficients; it will give a similar result for any ring $R$.

Answer (score 0):

$H_{n}(S^n;R)=R;H_{k}(S^n;R)=0,k\not=n$.And this does not rely on the property or ring $R$.

Comment: What if R had a torsion subgroup?

Comment: We can use Mayer-Vietoris Sequence on $\{S^n,S^n-p,S^n-q\}$ and this theorem does not rely on $R$. You can find the specific process on http://en.bookfi.org/book/509000 and page 190.